# Recursive Tree insertion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, tree

I try to write insert into a tree data structure recursively in javascript with tree-node, but don't get it working. 
So my question would be, how to approach the issue.

this is my data:

```
[ { id: 'a', children: [ 'b', 'c' ] },
  { id: 'b', children: [ '' ] },
  { id: 'c', children: [ 'b', 'd' ] },
  { id: 'd', children: [ 'b' ] } ]
```

I want that showing up in a tree like the following:

```
 a
/\
b c
  /\
 b  d
     \
      b
```

### Edit: Added code

I Thought i could do something like this, but that doesn't work... and of course has high complexity because of the nested forEach:

```
var Node = require("tree-node");
var testarray =     
[ 
{ id: 'a', children: [ 'b', 'c' ] },
{ id: 'b', children: [ '' ] },
{ id: 'c', children: [ 'b', 'd' ] },
{ id: 'd', children: [ 'b' ] } 
]

function appendChildRecursive(parent) {
    var childnode = new Node()
    var data = parent.data("children")
    testarray.forEach(function(item){
        if(data !== undefined) {
            data.forEach(function (child) {
                if (item.id == child) {
                    childnode.data("id", child).data("children", item.children)
                    childnode = appendChildRecursive(childnode)
                    parent.appendChild(childnode) 
                }
            })
        }

    })
    return parent
}

var root = new Node();
root.data("id",testarray[0].id).data("children",testarray[0].children)
root=appendChildRecursive(root)
```

Comment: do you really have node `b` twice? it generates a circular reference.

Comment: yes at least three times, but it doesn't create a circular as b is not pointing to one of it's callers.

Comment: how do you separate the nodes? or do you use a strict order beginning from the start and use only the last same named nodes?

Comment: That could be copys. It must not be the same node, just the values.

Comment: why `''` for a not given children?

Comment: had no reason, happend automatically while transforming my original data. I can take this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the last inserted nodes and keep the reference to the last nodes by overwriting the reference.

```js
var data = [{ id: 'a', children: ['b', 'c'] }, { id: 'b', children: [] }, { id: 'c', children: ['b', 'd'] }, { id: 'd', children: ['b'] }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var nodes = Object.create(null),
            r = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!nodes[a.id]) {
                nodes[a.id] = { id: a.id, children: [] };
                r = nodes[a.id];
            }
            a.children.forEach(function (b) {
                nodes[b] = { id: b, children: [] };
                nodes[a.id].children.push(nodes[b]);
            });
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You've passed the data in function as an array, but haven't used array anywhere and mutating data directly, why?

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is wrong.
Each 'leaf' should contain reference to the 'left' and 'right' element.
for example:

```
const first = { id: 'a', left: null, right: null };
const second = { id: 'b', left: null, right: first };
// etc...
```

The children approach would be more suitable for graph.
But you still have to store references, not ids.

Comment: but left/right is only for binary trees, no? In my case I could have more then two children, so I cannot make use of right and left.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's my miss. Still I would store references, not ids.